# Infinite recursion, spring mvc client is hanging

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, client

Got a problem with post method in Spring. When i'm trying to post object to database, the client app is hanging and i need to terminate it. Posting the object with curl is working normally. I'm getting log:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->dareq.Point["points"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->dareq.Point["points"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->dareq.Point["points"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->dareq.Point["points"]
```

Client side:

Point class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Point {
private Long id;
private List<String> bssid = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Double> rssi = new ArrayList<>();
private double x;
private double y;

public Point()
{

}

public Point(Long id, List<String> bssid, List<Double> rssi, double x, double y){
    this.id = id;
    this.bssid = bssid;
    this.rssi = rssi;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}


public long getid(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) { this.id=id; }

public List<String> getbssid(){
    return bssid;
}

public void setbssid(List<String> bssid)
{
    this.bssid=bssid;
}

public List<Double> getrssi(){
    return rssi;
}

public void setrssi(List<Double> rssi)
{
    this.rssi=rssi;
}

public Double getx(){
    return x;
}

public void setx(Double x){
    this.x=x;
}

public Double gety(){
    return y;
}

public void sety(Double y){
    this.y=y;
}

public List<Point> getPoints()
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<List<Point>> pointResponse = restTemplate.exchange("http://naviserv-env-1.4jdgmueexz.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/points/", HttpMethod.GET, null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Point>>()
            {});
    List<Point> points = pointResponse.getBody();
    return (points);
}

public Point getPoint(long id)
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Point point = restTemplate.getForObject("http://naviserv-env-1.4jdgmueexz.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/points/" + id, Point.class);
    return point;
}

public void postPoint()
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.postForObject("http://naviserv-env-1.4jdgmueexz.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/points", this, this.getClass());
}

public void deletePoint(Long id)
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.delete("http://localhost:5000/points/" + id);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Point{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' + ", " +
            "bssid='" + bssid + '\'' + ", " +
            "rssi='" + rssi + '\'' + ", " +
            "x='" + x + '\'' + ", " +
            "y='" + y + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

Server side:

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/points")
Points newPoints(@RequestBody Points newPoints){
return repository.save(newPoints);
}
```

Points class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Points {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    @Column
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> bssid;
    @Column
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Double> rssi;
    private double x;
    private double y;

Points (){
};

Points(List<String> bssid, List<Double> rssi, double x, double y){
    this.bssid=bssid;
    this.rssi=rssi;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
}
```

Checking logs on AWS server, when i try to post object on client, a lot of get methods are called:

```
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:31 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:32 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:32 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:32 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:32 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
```

I will really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Please post the entire class containing the Post function on client side.

Comment: @EugenCovaci edited post, with entire class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson interprets the method `public List<Point> getPoints()` as a getter for `points` property and calls it to get the value, hence the infinite recursion error.

**Solution**

Place `@JsonIgnore` on `public List<Point> getPoints()` (even better, on all non-getter methods) or rename it to, let's say, `public List<Point> points()` .

Comment: Thanks that worked ! Can you explain me why he interprets it as a getter for points ? It's just a naming problem?

Comment: Yes, Jackson uses conventions and you managed to fit right into one. Also you should think about refactoring your code. It is bad practice to implement logic in your data class. You should rather extract it to a `@Service` class. The class should depend on `RestTemplate` by making it a constructor parameter (`@Autowired`).

Comment: @Dariokoko It comes from JavaBean convention (Jackson thinks that class is a JavaBean). You can accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @ygor You're right that methods should be out of this class, thanks for advice. :)